# No internet after installing Ubuntu 14.04 on Inspiron

Tags: networking, drivers, dell

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows XP on an old Dell Inspiron 1521. When I tried Ubuntu from the pen drive, everything was peachy. However, after installing, internet doesn't work. I've tried to "create connection" by copying the MAC Adress from the Ubuntu trial version, but it won't let me save them. It claims there are "No network devices avilable".

Also, the system doesn't shut down propperly. It stays on the purple Ubuntu screen and shows the white dots blinking endlessly untill I turn the computer off manually.